# Calling Excel's worksheet function from vba code

Tags: vba, excel

With worksheetfunction's methods I can call from vba code a lot of excel's function without reinvent the wheel.
Unfortunately not all function are available there but other simple function can be find under vba library.
Now I need to use two functions:

- `address()`
- `indirect()`

But none of two is available as method of vba or worksheetfunction

(here what is available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822194(v=office.14).aspx)

Using the object browser on the editor I can't find those functions...
how can I do?

Comment: show code please, we can answer given the context.

Comment: `Range.Address` is what you are looking for.

Comment: IF() is also not available, because it has a direct vba equivalent.

Comment: in place of INDIRECT(): `Range("youraddressstring")`

Answer (score 2):

`INDIRECT` is a way of resolving a string, this can be done in VBA easily.  `ADDRESS` can also be found as a member of a `Range` object.  That's why they are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny example:

- **A1** contains the text *B1*
- **B1** contains the text *Gold*
- **C1** contains the formula:`=INDIRECT(A1)`

[image]

Example

| # | A | B | C | value in C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Ref | Value | Formula | Output |
| 1 | B1 | Gold | =INDIRECT(A1) | Gold |
| 2 | B2 | Silver | =INDIRECT(A2) | Silver |

Running this macro:

```
Sub UsingEvaluate()
    MsgBox Evaluate("INDIRECT(A1)")
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]